# Difficulty understanding Kernel & Range for all transformations aside from matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently learning about linear transformations and have been have a lot of difficulty understanding the Kernel and Range.

I understand the kernel for linear transformations defined by: T(**x**) = A**x**. It is simply the solution to the homogeneous system $A*x=0$. I understand how to solve for it too, (row reducing, finding free variables, etc).

But when given problems such as:

Consider the linear transformation $T:P_2 \rightarrow P_1$ defined by:
$T(ax^2+bx+c) = (a+b) + (b-c)x,$

where $a,b$ and $c$ are arbitrary real numbers. Determine Ker($T$), Range($T$), and their dimensions.

I struggle to find an answer. I am NOT looking for somebody to merely supply the answer, but rather provide an explanation for it, (I have a test in a few days). Thanks in advance.

Comment: To some extent, figuring out the kernel and range depends in the particular problem at hand. If $T p = 0$, this means that $(Tp)(x) = 0$ for all $x$. What does that say about $a,b,c$? For the range, can you figure out which polynomials in $P_1$ can be expressed in the form $Tp$ for some $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to answer your question.

The first, and the less useful or "morally" correct, is that every linear transformation is in fact a matrix, and you can take, for example, the space of polynomials of degree $2$ or less and represent each polynomial as a vector with three coordinates and make $T$ a matrix. This is not difficult to do at all (simply take $ax^2+bx+c$ to $(a,b,c)$ and construct the matrix accordingly), but the second way is often simpler and better.

The second answer, is that the definitions you gave for the kernel and image are not the general case. The usual definition of the kernel of a transformation $T$ is $\ker T = \{x : T(x)=0\}$.

When $T$ is linear this happens to be a linear space, because if $T(x)=T(y)=0$ then $T(\lambda x+\mu y)=\lambda T(x) + \mu T(y) = 0$. Thus, to find $\ker T$, all you have to do is find all the solutions $x$ to $T(x)=0$.

Note that in matrix representation this is equivalent to the definition you gave, but it's useful without matrices, too - specifically in your example, $T(ax^2+bx+c)=0$ if and only if $a+b=0$ and $b-c=0$, which means $\ker T$ consists of polynomials of the form $ax^2-ax-a$. This has one free parameter, so its dimension is $1$.

The image of a transformation $T$ is defined to be $\mbox{Im } T = \{T(x) : x\in V \}$, where $V$ is the linear space on which $T$ is defined. This is also a linear space, because $\lambda T(x) + \mu T(y) = T(\lambda x + \mu y)$ when $T$ is linear.

This can also be used without going through matrices. In your example: $\mbox{Im } T = \{(b-c)x + (a+b) : a,b,c \mbox{ are arbitrarily chosen}\}$. If we select $b=0$, we get all the polynomials of the form $-cx+a$, and since $a,c$ are chosen arbitrarily, these are in fact all the polynomials of degree $1$ or less - a two-dimensional linear space (there are two free parameters). Note that letting $b$ change would not add any new polynomials, so it doesn't add another free variable.

Hope this helps you work a little more easily with linear transformations and good luck with the test.

Comment: thanks a lot man! much appreciated :)